# sed or awk add content to a body of a c function running in git bash v2.21.0

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

To turn this function in a c file (test.c)

```
void Fuction(uint8, var)
{
  dosomething();
}
// void Fuction(uint8, var)
// should not be injected below a comment with same pattern content
```

into:

```
void Fuction(uint8, var)
{
  injected1();
  injected2();
  injected3();
  dosomething();
}
// void Fuction(uint8, var)
// should not be injected below a comment with same pattern content
```

By injecting this one (inject.c)

```
injected1();
injected2();
injected3();
```

I tried several approaches with sed and awk but actually i was not able to inject the code below the open curly braces the code was injected before the curly braces.

On a regex website I was able to select the pattern including the curly braces, but in my script it did not work. May be awk is more compatible, but I have no deeper experiance with awk may some one coeld help here?

With awk i had a additional problem to pass the pattern variable with an ^ancor

call in git bash should be like this:

```
./inject.sh "void Fuction(uint8, var)" test.c inject.c
```

(my actual inject.sh bash script)

```
PATTERN=$1
FILE=$2
INJECTFILE=$3

sed -i "/^$PATTERN/r $INJECTFILE" $FILE
#sed -i "/^$PATTERN\r\{/r $INJECTFILE" $FILE
```

I actually have no idear to catch also the \n and the { in the next line
My result is:

```
void Fuction(uint8, var)
injected1();
injected2();
injected3();
{
  dosomething();
}
// void Fuction(uint8, var)
// should not be injected below a comment with same pattern content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on OP's `sed` code:

```
sed "/^${PATTERN}/,/{/ {
/{/ r ${INJECTFILE}
}" $FILE

# or as a one-liner

sed -e "/^${PATTERN}/,/{/ {" -e "/{/ r ${INJECTFILE}" -e "}" $FILE
```

Where:

- `/^${PATTERN}/,/{/` finds range of rows starting with `^${PATTERN}` and ending with a line that contains a `{`
- `{ ... }` within that range ...
- `/{/ r ${INJECTFILE}` - find the line containing a `{` and append the contents of `${INJECTFILE}`

Results:

```
$ ./inject.sh "void Fuction(uint8, var)" test.c inject.c
void Fuction(uint8, var)
{
injected1();
injected2();
injected3();
  dosomething();
}
// void Fuction(uint8, var)
// should not be injected below a comment with same pattern content
```

Once OP verifies the output the `-i` flag can be added to force `sed` to overwrite the file.

**NOTE:** OP's expected output shows the injected lines with some additional leading white space; if the intention is to auto-indent the injected lines to match with the current lines ... I'd probably want to look at something like `awk` in order to provide the additional formatting.